# Drupal 7 EntityFieldQuery fieldCondition for taxonomy field (multiple values) NOT IN my Exclude Array

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7, field

I have a taxonomy field with (usually multiple) terms attached (article_secondary_tags).  In my fieldCondition I want to test that all of the terms are NOT IN the exclude array ($exclude_terms). If ANY of the terms are in the array, that node should be excluded from the result. Here is what I have so far.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
          $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
            ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
            ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
            ->fieldCondition('article_primary_tag', 'tid', $exclude_terms, 'NOT IN')
            ->fieldCondition('article_secondary_tags', 'tid', $exclude_terms, 'NOT IN')
            ->fieldCondition('aw_article_primary_tag', 'tid', $landingterms)
            ->propertyOrderBy('created', 'DESC')
            ->range(0, $itemsneeded);
          $result = $query->execute();
```

The Primary tag field is excluding the node properly, but this field is a single taxonomy term. Also, if there is only one term referenced in the secondary tags, and it is in exclude_terms, it will work properly. The real problem is getting it to exclude the node from the queue if just one of the several secondary tags is in the $exclude_terms array. Almost like an "ALL NOT IN" operator would be needed.

Note: I'm using the primary tag to pull articles in (if that term id is in $landingterms). But they should not be included if they have a secondary tag that is to be excluded.

Thanks in advance for any hints and answers.  Can't figure this one out!

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

When you pass an array the operator becomes an OR. It's not nice but you could do a foreach.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
    ->fieldCondition('article_primary_tag', 'tid', $exclude_terms, 'NOT IN')
    ->fieldCondition('aw_article_primary_tag', 'tid', $landingterms)
    ->propertyOrderBy('created', 'DESC')
    ->range(0, $itemsneeded);

foreach ($exclude_terms as $exclude_term) {
  $query->fieldCondition('article_secondary_tags', 'tid', $exclude_term, 'NOT IN');
}

$result = $query->execute();
```